# Asciidoc.js - Get AsciiDoc Source from parsed Document

Tags: typescript, asciidoctor

I am trying to parse an AsciiDoc File with asciidoc.js, finding some sections and applying them to a new file in rearranged order.

I am able to parse the file, finding the sections I want, but I am not able to retrieve either the original AscciDoc code for that section or regenerate it from the AST.

package.json

```
dependencies": {
[...]
    "asciidoctor.js": "^1.5.9"
[...]
```

script.ts

```
const asciidoctor = require("asciidoctor.js")();
const changelogDoc = asciidoctor.loadFile(
  "../user-manual/src/main/asciidoc/Changelog.adoc"
);
[...]
for (const sec of changelogDoc.getSections()) {
      for (const subsec of sec.getSections()) {
        for (const subsubsec of subsec.getSections()) {
          if (subsubsec.hasTitle()) {
            const key = subsubsec.getTitle().match(/X[A-Z]+-[0-9]+/);
            if(key) {
                // Here it returns the rendered HTML content. How to get the AsciiDoc?
                return subsubsec.getContent();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Further investigation lead me here: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/2536 Looks like the use case for the API is not covered yet.

Comment: Found by investigating the objects: `let asciiDocSource = '';
              for(const b of subsubsec.blocks) {
                for(const line of b.lines) {
                  asciiDocSource += line + '\n';
                }
                asciiDocSource += '\n';
              }
              console.log(asciiDocSource);
              customIssueTexts[key] = asciiDocSource;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
for(const b of subsubsec.blocks) { 
  for(const line of b.lines) { 
    asciiDocSource += line + '\n'; 
  } asciiDocSource += '\n'; 
} 
console.log(asciiDocSource); 
return asciiDocSource;
```